# CSS on SAPUI5 Controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sapui5

I have a sap.m.Input inside a div tag in HTML view of sapui5. When I apply css to the div, it works fine on all the div elements. However, I want to apply css on a single control inside the div tag. It is not working. The code is :

```
<div data-sap-ui-type="sap.m.Label" data-text="Sr.No :"></div>
<div data-sap-ui-type="sap.m.Input" id="id_SrNo_Val" data-width ="10%"></div>
```

The above code does not work if I apply css to the input. It works fine on the label. I am trying to reduce the height of the input. It works on Chrome console with runtime id. However I want to apply css with the given id which it does not accept.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `SAPUI5` we don't know at which point time of `CSS` is applied to the `Controls`.

So you've to give **"priority to your css class or id"** which can be achieved using the `property` **!important**

Add your `CSS property` like following

```
#id_SrNo_Val {
     height : 10px !important;
     color : blue !important;
}
```

Use anything you want with `!important` property.

Update: Avoid `!important` because it'll become harder to debug at some point of time. Also in CSS, it's not suggested to use.

Comment: @arthan-v Thanks for the answer but could there be any issue with '! important' as it is not that much recommended.

Comment: @abhhab - There won't be any issue, unless you're using it in `class` and applying that `class` to everywhere, because you may not want that style in everywhere. careful in giving `!important` it'll overwrite all other style property you gave.

Comment: @arthan-v - I am using this with class because it is not working with the id. When I apply the '!important' with id in my stylesheet, it does not work. However it works fine when I use class.

Comment: it should work with `id` also. but make sure that `class` is not affecting your `height` in any other `view`.

Comment: try to avoid `!important` by all means, instead go for classes

Answer (score 2):

You may assign additional class to a control adding `class="yourStylingClass"` attribute.

You shouldn't use control ids for styling, since SAPUI5 may modify those, add prefixes etc.